# How to escape double quotes with string interpolation

Tags: c#

I have this:

```
var s = $"my name is {model.Name}":
```

and I want the string to be:

"my name is "someone""

How can I do this?

Comment: the same way you do it without string interpolation?

Comment: @bernlim No, string interpolation is something different than the string verbatim.

Answer (score 24):

Simply like you would do without string interpolation:

```
var s = $"my name is \"{model.Name}\"";
```

With the string verbatim it gets a little different:

```
var s = $@"my name is ""{model.Name}""";
```

Comment: This is what I get "my name is \"someone\""

Comment: No, you don't. You are looking at the debugger, aren't you?

Comment: Next question here on SO: how to remove the \ char in the string, `string.Replace()` doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the backslash like this:

```
var s = $"my name is \"{model.Name}\"";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use double quote escape `\"`:

```
var s = $"my name is \"{model.name}\"";
```

You can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-escapes-in-regular-expressions#character-escapes-in-net) and [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available/) more character escape sequences available in .NET.

Comment: @PatrickHofman oh, my bad, didn't see it, but i guess the reference to Character Escapes in .NET is usefull